# Losing more rep than expected during a downvote

Tags: support, down-votes

I seem to have lost too much reputation for a single down vote to an answer that I made for my own question. I lost the normal 2 reputation, but I also seemed to have lost a second set of 2, totalling 4 reputation lost on a single down vote.

Is this the expected behaviour, or did something go wrong?

Comment: The [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17352681/ios-internationalization-storyboards-not-showing) in question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You received one on the question as well (someone's in a grumpy mood because Santa hasn't come yet).

> [image]

It happens to list the reputation lost for both the question and answer in your profile, labeled with the title of the question.

> [image]

Comment: Noted, thank you. I didn't think rep was lost for questions. Thanks.

Comment: @JustinWood you don't lose rep for *casting* a down vote on a question.  You lose 1 rep for *casting* a down vote on an answer.  Having a question or answer that is down voted is -2.

Comment: A lump of coal has been dispatched to the down voter, thank you for the report. And it's not even a _medium_ sized lump of coal, I sent the smallest one we had.

Comment: @TinyTim Every bit helps. Home heating is expensive, even for the wretched.

Comment: +1 for managing to work in a hand drawn circle.

Comment: @MrLister Labeling it with a textbox would have been blasphemy during the Hat season.

Answer (score 5):

This is because someone downvoted both your answer and question.

So what you are seeing is -2 for the answer downvote, and -2 for the question downvote. That is why it is listed twice in your recent reputation changes on your profile summary.

Sometimes it can be hard to tell this happens when the net total is 0 (as it is for the question you asked), but if broken apart<sup>1</sup> (by clicking on the post score), it is actually +1, -1 (at the time I am writing this at least).

<sup>1. In order to see the breakdown of the votes, you must be an ["Established User"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/established-user) by earning at least 1000 reputation on Stack Overflow</sup>